# What is your top 3 of most used types of sound-fx for Cartoon Sound Design?

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects, sound-libraries, animation, cartoon

Do you have experience in sound-design or sound-editing for Cartoon Sound Design? If so, what is your top 3 of most used types of sound-fx? (e.g.: whistles, twangs, bounces, boings, rattles, whooshes, stretching sounds, etc...)

Comment: Let me rephrase my question. Maybe it was not clear what I was aiming for:
If an evil government would force you to only use three types of sound-fx for cartoon from now on, which ones would you choose? ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The audience also has an opinion nowadays and the typical slapstick sounds stick out because of over usage. It depends on the scene/setting ofcourse.

I've never used those type of sounds and always try to create something new for cartoonish SFX. It works just as well (or better) and keeps things interesting for me, the client and the audience.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking the typical slide whistle up or down, instant classic.